# useEffect is never triggering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am writing a React-Native app using Expo. When I try to render the below page on my devices, I get errors that `memorialDetails.Name` is undefined. From what I can tell, useEffect is just not executing no matter what, which is causing the API calls to not trigger, hence the undefined data.

I have confirmed via console.log statements and from watching the backend logs that the API calls are not being triggered.

Here is an Expo Snack that you can look at that shows the issue. Line 30 on MemorialDetailScreen.js can be changed from a token to plain text to make the page render, and then as soon as it is changed back to a token, it crashes.

https://snack.expo.dev/@djfriar/memorialmanager

When I run this, I see the following in the console, so the useEffect is never getting called. It seems like the app is trying to render the entire screen before calling the API:

```
iOS Bundling complete 51ms
==== MemorialListScreen ====
==== memorial API ====
==== MemorialNavigator ====
iOS Running app on iPhone 12 mini
==== memorialID ====
9
===== memorialDetails =====
undefined
==== memorialID ====
9
===== memorialDetails =====
undefined
```

I have forced refresh, restarted the entire app / Expo, etc. It does this on both my iOS and Android dev devices.

Comment: How is this `MemorialDetailScreen` component being rendered? Are you directly invoking it like a function instead of passing it as JSX to be rendered by React?

Comment: @DrewReese In my App.js I'm just returning this component. I added the exact code to the end of my question.

Comment: I suspect there may be a problem in your `jsx` because after a successful initial render `useEffect` will get called. so instead of adding logs, try removing all `jsx` code and just put a simple placeholder in your jsx and then debug if useEffect is working or not.

Comment: I agree with Saagar, so long as React is rendering this `MemorialDetailScreen` there really is no reason why the `useEffect` hook won't be called at least once. If possible, try creating an [Expo Snack](https://expo.dev/) demo of your code that we can inspect and debug live.

Comment: I have created an Expo Snack here: https://snack.expo.dev/@djfriar/memorialmanager. It is currently showing the error in the Snack, but that server it is pointing at is live. Also, I should note that on my local machine I deleted this whole page and built it again piecemeal; and it worked as I was going until I force reloaded, so best I can guess is some sort of caching or persistence issue...

Comment: I tweaked the Snack a bit so now if you change line 30 to be just plain text, the page will render as expected; but as soon as you change it to {memorialDetails.Name}, it crashes. However, locally I see it hitting the API and getting the proper data when I first make the edit, and then force reloading will cause the crash and it never tries to hit the API.

Comment: @DrewReese - I have updated the question to have the Expo Snack link in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `useEffect` is guaranteed to be called at least once on the initial render cycle. You've a bug in the render return that prevents the hook from firing at the end of the render cycle.

On the initial render the `useApi` hook is returning an object with a `data` property that is an empty array.

```
export default useApi = (apiFunc) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const request = async (...args) => {
    console.log("==== useApi ====");

    setLoading(true);
    const response = await apiFunc(...args);
    console.log(response.data);
    setLoading(false);

    if (!response.ok) return setError(true);
    
    setError(false);
    setData(response.data);
  };

  return { data, error, loading, request };
};
```

...

```
const getMemorialDetailsApi = useApi(memorial.getMemorialDetails);
```

On the next line you access the zeroth element

```
const memorialDetails = getMemorialDetailsApi.data[0];
```

which is obviously going to be undefined. This will throw an error during the initial render when attempting to access the property of undefined.

```
<AppText style={styles.memorialName}>
  {memorialDetails.Name}
</AppText>
```

To guard against this you can use the [Optional Chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) on ensure the `data` array exists ***and*** provide a valid fallback value.

```
const memorialDetails = getMemorialDetailsApi.data?.[0] ?? {};
```

This allows there to *at least* always be a defined object to reference nested properties from later.